# App force close without internet JSON

Tags: android, json

im making an app using json on first activity but when the app is open without internet conection the app make a "force close", i dont know what have to do to ovoid this error, help, im new on android and java

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
String TITLES[] = {"Que es CMX","Ejecutivos(as)","Nuestros Servicios","Soluciones a tu Medida","Certificaciones Vigentes", "Cursos Online", "", "", "", ""};

int ICONS[] = {R.mipmap.organization,R.mipmap.conference,R.mipmap.services,R.mipmap.approval,R.mipmap.diploma1,R.mipmap.donate,R.id.linea,R.id.linea,R.id.linea,R.mipmap.home};

String NAME = "John Doe";
String EMAIL = "johndoe@cmx.org.mx";
int PROFILE = R.drawable.profile1;

private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle
// Declare Variables
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
static String RANK = "title";
static String COUNTRY = "place";
static String POPULATION = "date";
static String CONTENT1 = "content1";
static String CONTENT2 = "content2";
static String FLAG = "imagen";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    setTitle(R.string.title_activity_main);



    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE,this);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
    // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
    // and header view profile picture

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

    final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

    });


    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());



            if(child !=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)){
                Drawer.closeDrawers();

                if (recyclerView.getChildPosition(child) == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Profile.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else if
                        (recyclerView.getChildPosition(child) == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CMX.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else if
                        (recyclerView.getChildPosition(child) == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ejecutivos.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else if
                        (recyclerView.getChildPosition(child) == 3){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Servicios.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else if
                        (recyclerView.getChildPosition(child) == 4){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Soluciones.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else if
                        (recyclerView.getChildPosition(child) == 5) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Certificaciones.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else if
                        (recyclerView.getChildPosition(child) == 6){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Web.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }else if
                        (recyclerView.getChildPosition(child) == 8 ){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }
    });


    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


    Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
            // open I am not going to put anything here)
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
        }



    }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
    Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State
}

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://cmx.org.mx/wp-content/uploads/json.txt");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("posts");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                map.put("place", jsonobject.getString("place"));
                map.put("date", jsonobject.getString("date"));
                map.put("content1", jsonobject.getString("content1"));
                map.put("content2", jsonobject.getString("content2"));
                map.put("imagen", jsonobject.getString("imagen"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case R.id.about:

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

```
 public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

-Edit

Logcat:
https://goo.gl/N1YQ9T

Update1:

```
        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://cmx.org.mx/wp-content/uploads/json.txt");

    if(jsonobject==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("posts");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                map.put("place", jsonobject.getString("place"));
                map.put("date", jsonobject.getString("date"));
                map.put("content1", jsonobject.getString("content1"));
                map.put("content2", jsonobject.getString("content2"));
                map.put("imagen", jsonobject.getString("imagen"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        return null;
    }
```

MyAdapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;  // Declaring Variable to Understand which View is being worked on
// IF the view under inflation and population is header or Item
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

private String mNavTitles[]; // String Array to store the passed titles Value from MainActivity.java
private int mIcons[];       // Int Array to store the passed icons resource value from MainActivity.java

private String name;        //String Resource for header View Name
private int profile;        //int Resource for header view profile picture
private String email;       //String Resource for header view email
Context context;


// Creating a ViewHolder which extends the RecyclerView View Holder
// ViewHolder are used to to store the inflated views in order to recycle them

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    int Holderid;

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    ImageView profile;
    TextView Name;
    TextView email;
    Context contxt;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView,int ViewType,Context c) {                 // Creating ViewHolder Constructor with View and viewType As a parameter
        super(itemView);
        contxt = c;
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


        // Here we set the appropriate view in accordance with the the view type as passed when the holder object is created

        if(ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText); // Creating TextView object with the id of textView from item_row.xml
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);// Creating ImageView object with the id of ImageView from item_row.xml
            Holderid = 1;                                               // setting holder id as 1 as the object being populated are of type item row
        }
        else{


            Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);         // Creating Text View object from header.xml for name
            email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);       // Creating Text View object from header.xml for email
            profile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleView);// Creating Image view object from header.xml for profile pic
            Holderid = 0;                                                // Setting holder id = 0 as the object being populated are of type header view
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(contxt, "The Item Clicked is: " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    }



MyAdapter(String Titles[],int Icons[],String Name,String Email, int Profile, Context passedContext){ // MyAdapter Constructor with titles and icons parameter
    // titles, icons, name, email, profile pic are passed from the main activity as we
        mNavTitles = Titles;                //have seen earlier
    mIcons = Icons;
    name = Name;
    email = Email;
    profile = Profile;
    this.context = passedContext;    //here we assign those passed values to the values we declared here
    //in adapter

}



//Below first we ovverride the method onCreateViewHolder which is called when the ViewHolder is
//Created, In this method we inflate the item_row.xml layout if the viewType is Type_ITEM or else we inflate header.xml
// if the viewType is TYPE_HEADER
// and pass it to the view holder

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

        ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

        return vhItem; // Returning the created object

        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder

    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header,parent,false); //Inflating the layout

        ViewHolder vhHeader = new ViewHolder(v,viewType,context); //Creating ViewHolder and passing the object of type view

        return vhHeader; //returning the object created


    }
    return null;

}

//Next we override a method which is called when the item in a row is needed to be displayed, here the int position
// Tells us item at which position is being constructed to be displayed and the holder id of the holder object tell us
// which view type is being created 1 for item row
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder.Holderid ==1) {                              // as the list view is going to be called after the header view so we decrement the
        // position by 1 and pass it to the holder while setting the text and image
        holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position - 1]); // Setting the Text with the array of our Titles
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(mIcons[position -1]);// Settimg the image with array of our icons
    }
    else{

        holder.profile.setImageResource(profile);           // Similarly we set the resources for header view
        holder.Name.setText(name);
        holder.email.setText(email);
    }
}

// This method returns the number of items present in the list
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNavTitles.length+1; // the number of items in the list will be +1 the titles including the header view.
}


// Witht the following method we check what type of view is being passed
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}
```

Comment: There could be 1000 reasons of force close. Please post you proper error logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getJSONfromURL()` catches all the Exceptions I can think of, so the issue is probably not there.

The issue is that it returns `null` when an Exception has been caught.

So `jsonobject` is null when you have no Internet, and then you're accessing it as if it's not null at `jsonobject.getJSONArray("posts")`.

I suggest you check if `jsonobject == null` just after the line with `jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(...);`

**Edit (following comment):**

The error is probably due to this line of code in MainActivity.
`int ICONS[] = {R.mipmap.organization,R.mipmap.conference,R.mipmap.services,R.mipmap.approval,R.mipmap.diploma1,R.mipmap.donate,R.id.linea,R.id.linea,R.id.linea,R.mipmap.home};`

All items in the `ICONS` array should either be R.mipmap.xxxx or R.drawable.xxxx, and not R.id.xxxx or others. To see if this is the issue, replace all the `R.id.linea` with `R.mipmap.conference` for testing purposes, and let us know what happens then.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. Does your app still crash?

Comment: Just saw your Logcat, please post the code for the class MyAdapter.

Comment: Finaly!, just change the toast to intent

Comment: I did that for a separation of an icon, because i dont know how put a line to separate the elements in the navigation drawer. http://goo.gl/hfs8N3

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Create an array
    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
    jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://cmx.org.mx/wp-content/uploads/json.txt");

    if(jsonobject==null){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CMX.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
}else{

    try {
        // Locate the array name in JSON
        jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("posts");
```